# Defining electric potential energy

Tags: electricity, charge, potential-energy

When we say that the electric potential energy at a point is X is that assuming we are using a positive test charge?

Comment: we don't say that.

Comment: my textbook does say that for both for electric potential energy and electric potential.  i.e. http://imgur.com/R1Q3xC2

Comment: @user41049 I only see "electric potential" in the linked image.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing "electric potential" and "electric potential energy". I don't blame you, it's an unfortunate bit of terminology. The electric potential energy is defined for a particular charge (or distribution of charges), and so you need to explicitly put in the charge of the point or distribution of interest. That is, we don't talk about the electric potential energy at a point of space, we talk about the electric potential energy of a particular charge *at* that point.

On the other hand, the electric potential, full stop, at a particular point is defined as the electric potential energy *per unit charge* at that point. So, there is no assumption about the sign or magnitude of the charge because we're explicitly dividing it out.

In both cases, we need a reference point which is arbitrary. So, really the full statement would be, "The electric potential at a point, relative to this other point, is X."

Comment: No I really do understand the difference between the two.  Electric potential energy is dependent on the test charge in question.  A test charge with double the charge will have double the electric potential energy.  However, electric potential is electric potential energy per unit charge, so it's not dependent on the test charge.

Comment: I should clarify what I don't understand:  When people say U(at some random point near the source charge) = 6 joules or when people say V(at some random point near the source charge) = 4 V, they are saying that the work to move a test charge from infinity to that position is 6 joules or the 4 joules/coulomb.  My question is, are they making that calculation with a positive or negative test charge?

Comment: Again, we *don't* say the things you're saying. We would say, "The potential energy *of a +1C charge* at this point is..." or, "The potential energy of a -6C charge at this point is..." The statement is incomplete unless you explicitly say what charge you're talking about. With the electric potential, it doesn't matter because, as I said, we're dividing the charge out. You could do the calculation with a positive charge q and calculate U/q = V or you could do it with a negative charge and calculate -U/-q = V. It comes out the same either way.

Comment: The image of your textbook you posted above is completely in line with what I'm saying, so I'm not entirely sure what the point of confusion is.

Comment: Hm, I should have written this question not with electric potential energy but with voltage.  Please replace everything I've said above with electric potential energy with voltage.  So if you were to read the [this](http://imgur.com/R1Q3xC2) in my textbook, is 6V measured in terms of a positive or negative test charge?

Comment: It doesn't matter! You can calculate the potential energy using a positive charge and divide out the positive charge to get the electric potential, or do the same calculation with a negative charge, get negative the potential energy, and then divide out the negative again.

Comment: Also, now you're throwing "voltage" (the *difference* in electric potential between two points) into the mix. These are not interchangeable words. I'm not convinced you fully understand the difference, so I think you should spend some time reviewing your definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The potential energy of a particle with charge $q$ in a *conservative* electric field $\vec E$ is

$$U = q\phi$$

where the electric potential $\phi$ is related the electric field by

$$\vec E = -\nabla \phi$$

Thus, the electric potential is defined, up to a non-physical constant, by the associated electric field - no test charge enters the picture.

The value of the electric field at a point has a clear physical meaning - it is the *normalized* force on a charged particle, i.e., the force per unit charge.

$$\vec F = q \vec E $$

So, for example, if you have a test particle with charge $q$ and a force $\vec F$ is measured, the electric field is

$$\vec E = \frac{\vec F_q}{q} $$

which is thus *independent* of the charge $q$.

To be clear, if you were then measure the force on a test particle with charge $-q$, you would find

$$\vec F_{-q} = - \vec F_q $$

and thus

$$\frac{\vec F_q}{q} =  \frac{\vec F_{-q}}{-q} = \vec E$$

Similarly, for the electric potential

$$\frac{U_q}{q} =  \frac{U_{-q}}{-q} = \phi$$

Answer (score 0):

The value of **electric potential difference** (aka voltage) is **independent of the choice of test charge,** including its sign. When determining the electric potential difference between two points, you can imagine either a positive or negative test charge, which ever one tickles your fancy. Note that the same cannot be said about electric potential energy.

As a short example, consider a test charge that moves to the right in the presence of an external electric field that also points to the right. Let's say we're interested in the potential difference $V$. If the test charge is positive the work done by the field is positive (force in same direction as displacement), so $V=-W_\text{by field}/q<0$. If the test charge is negative, the work done by the field is negative, so $V=-W_\text{by field}/q<0$ again. In this last expression, there are three negatives: the definition, the work, and the charge.

As mentioned above, the same independence is not true of electric potential energy. Basically, you don't divide out by the test charge $q$ in the above expression, so the change in sign due to $W_\text{by field}$ doesn't cancel out.